# Pb of Fortran <-> C++ interoperability if I compile the fortran with the option -finit-local-zero

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, linker, fortran

I've found out a strange result while linking a program with C++ and Fortran.
The test (see after) is very simple : define a variable in a fortran module and access it in the C++ program. 
If I compile the fortran (gfortran from GCC 7.4.0) with the option "-finit-local-zero" then the link fails complaining about a multiple definition of the variables. Of course, if I suppress this option, it works well but it's a pb for me cause I need to set to "0" my uninitialized data.

I put here after the fortran code, the C++ code and the commands for making the exe.

```
        module A_module

        USE ISO_C_BINDING
        implicit none
        real(C_FLOAT) , bind(C) :: isareal
        integer(C_INT), bind(C, NAME="MMS") :: MMS 

        CONTAINS

        subroutine CHANGE() bind(c)
        use iso_c_binding
        implicit none
        isareal = 5.0 
        MMS=40
        write(*,*) 'fortran changes isareal =>',isareal
        write(*,*) 'fortran changes MMS =>',MMS
        end subroutine CHANGE
        end module
```

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

//Fortran definitions "translated" to C++
extern "C" {
void change();
float isareal;
int MMS; // 
}
int main() {
    // Can access to a variable in a fortran module ? 
    cout << "In C before: isareal = " << isareal;
    cout << " and MMS = " << MMS << "\n";

    change(); //call fortran to change the values 

    // Control
    cout << "In C after: isareal = " << isareal;
    cout << " and MMS = " << MMS << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

And the commands:

```
 mpif90  -finit-local-zero -c mod_A_module.f
 mpicxx -Wextra -std=c++11 -c cpp_main_1.cpp
 mpif90 *.o -std=c++11 -lstdc++ -o bad.exe
./bad.exe
```

here is the error (when using -finit-local-zero)

```
mod_A_module.o:(.bss+0x0): multiple definition of `isareal'
cpp_main_1.o:(.bss+0x0): first defined here
mod_A_module.o:(.bss+0x4): multiple definition of `MMS'
cpp_main_1.o:(.bss+0x4): first defined here
```

Thank you in advance for your help...

Comment: I thought `Pb` was the chemical name for `lead`, but don't think you mean that.  What do you mean by `Pb` ?

Comment: Your comment says IMPORTANT TO WRITE "mms" and NOT "MMS".
You've written MMS.

Comment: Thanks for the remarks: Comment on "MMS" or "mms" : it is not directly related to the pb (problem), it was just to note that if we don't explicitely name the binding bind(C), name="MMS" in the fortran, then this variable becomes "mms" (it was just for not forgetting that).  The 'real' problem is the fact that I cannot compile the fortran code with the flag I am mentioning in my post

Comment: Is there a problem (pb) with atually writing `MMS = 0` in the Fortran code?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is actually (partially, at least) in the C++ code. You haven't told that `isareal` and `MMS` are external, so the compiler will generate an "instantiated" symbol (quotes because I don't remember the correct term) for those. You can see that with e.g. "readelf -s main.o"

```
0000000000000000     4 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT    4 MMS
```

The crucial thing to note here is that the `Ndx` column (the next to final column, next to the symbol name) says that `MMS` is in section #4.

If you fix the C++ code by adding `extern` to the `isareal` and `MMS` declarations you'll see that the section numbers change to `UND`, meaning that it's a reference to a symbol in some other object file, to be resolved by the linker.

The second part of the puzzle is that if you compile the Fortran code with `-finit-local-zero`, the Fortran compiler will also generate "instantiated" symbols. And then when you try to link them together you get the "multiple definition" error.  Now, if you omit the `-finit-local-zero` option, GFortran will put those two symbols in the `COM` section (short for `COMDAT`), which is a special kind of section where multiple definitions are allowed. I'm not sure why this is done, though I'd guess `COMDAT` doesn't allow symbols that are initialized to some value.

If you search the GCC bugzilla, you'll find a bunch of Fortran issues related to the multiple definitions problem, all interconnected in a maze of twisty little passages.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that

```
extern "C" {
  void change();
  float isareal;
  int MMS; // 
}
```

*defines* storage for these variables.  It doesn't merely declare them. 
 Here's a simple example:

```
$ cat x.cpp 
extern "C" { int foo; }
$ make x.o
g++    -c -o x.o x.cpp
$ nm x.o
0000000000000000 B foo
```

extern "C" doesn't make the *variables* extern; it defines the linkage to be of the C convention, i.e. unmangled function names.  Since file-scope variable names are not mangled (they can't be overloaded), there's no need to keep them there:

```
extern "C" {
  void change();
}
extern float isareal;
extern int MMS;
```

should do the trick.

It may be that by using -finit-local-zero you prevented the linker from coalescing the two otherwise identical global definitions.

Comment: Thanks a lot, James, the explanation is clear and the modification works just fine.